# Ag-grid Custom data on Expansion

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I am looking for a way to display the data in the form of normal HTML/CSS styling(not the row form or other table form )

I am unable to find any documentation upon this

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I got it solved. Thank you for the reply.
The question was about the Custom Detail.